# Clang bug with std::function, std::bind and std::ref?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, clang

It seems the following code doesn't compile under clang (llvm version 5.0):

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::function<void(int&)> f;
    std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(f, std::ref(i));
}
```

If `f` is declared as follows (i.e., not a `std::function`), then it compiles fine:

```
void f(int& n1);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this really a compiler bug?

This is the compiler error I am getting:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:465:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:599:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/tuple:234:73: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::reference_wrapper<int>'
             _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_default_constructible<_Hp>::value) : value()
                                                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/tuple:447:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tuple_leaf<0, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int>, false>::__tuple_leaf' requested here
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR __tuple_impl()
                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/tuple:550:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tuple_impl<std::__1::__tuple_indices<0>, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >::__tuple_impl' requested
      here
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR tuple()
                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1744:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::tuple<std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >::tuple' requested here
          __bound_args_(_VSTD::forward<_BA>(__bound_args)...) {}
          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2243:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int>
      >::__bind<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >, , void>' requested here
              __first_(_VSTD::forward<_Args1>(get<_I1>(__first_args))...)
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2421:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &,
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > >, 2>::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &,
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > &&, , 0, >' requested here
            : base(__pc, _VSTD::move(__first_args), _VSTD::move(__second_args),
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:992:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &,
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > > >::__compressed_pair<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > &&, >'
      requested here
        : __f_(piecewise_construct, _VSTD::forward_as_tuple(_VSTD::move(__f)),
          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1277:26: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__function::__func<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &,
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > >, void ()>::__func' requested here
            ::new (__f_) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f));
                         ^
test.cpp:7:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::function<void ()>::function<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int &)> &, std::__1::reference_wrapper<int> > >' requested here
        std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(f, std::ref(i));
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__functional_base:365:31: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__f', but no arguments were provided
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY reference_wrapper(type& __f) _NOEXCEPT : __f_(&__f) {}
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__functional_base:367:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    private: reference_wrapper(type&&); public: // = delete; // do not bind to temps
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__functional_base:354:24: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS reference_wrapper
                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__functional_base:354:24: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
1 error generated.
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of other issues than the one you cite; maybe you should address them first.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Both GCC 4.8.1 as well as [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/932f5cb191b02492) (3.5trunk) compile it just fine.

Comment: @scott What other issues?I've updated the post with a complete example code and the error output of this simple program to make it clear that there is no other code giving problems.

Comment: @DanielFrey Does Coliru use libstdc++, or libc++? If there's a difference between libstdc++ and libc++, that would also explain it, and would still make it fail with newer clang versions.

Comment: @hvd By default they seem to use libstdc++ and if you supply -stdlib=libc++, the [linker fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b064fe446faff65). Hm, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Thats my solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459241/ios-tesseract-with-c11-support

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The bug is fixed in version 5.1

Comment: @CanÜrek That code did not compile when I was using XCode 5.0.
I updated XCode (and thus also clang) to 5.1 as soon as they released it. The code compiled perfectly afterwards.
I have a project using similar code, it would be stupid to announce that I can finally compile my library on mac when it isn't fixed, wouldn't it?
I don't have a mac to check now, but at least when I posted it the bug was fixed.