# IOS Tesseract with c++11 support

Tags: ios, xcode, c++11, tesseract

I am using some codes and that codes need c++11 support. But not working any version of tesseract with c++11 support. What can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. Your target => General => Linked Frameworks and Libraries => + => libstdc++.6.0.9 Just add that framework